# How to download pdf files from URLs leading to sub-URLs using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, request, urllib

I am trying to download all pdf files from the links in the following URLs:

```
https://www.adb.org/projects/documents/country/ban/year/2020?terms=education
https://www.adb.org/projects/documents/country/ban/year/2019?terms=education
https://www.adb.org/projects/documents/country/ban/year/2018?terms=education
```

These URLs have lists of links which directs to sub-links containing pdf files. The lists of links in the main URLs come from the search result of a country, year and a term.

I have tried with the following codes by changing it in different ways. However, it does not seem to be working. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
import os
import time
from glob import glob 
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 
url = ["https://www.adb.org/projects/documents/country/ban/year/2020?terms=education",
      "https://www.adb.org/projects/documents/country/ban/year/2019?terms=education",
      "https://www.adb.org/projects/documents/country/ban/year/2018?terms=education"]

folder = glob("J:/pdfs/*/")

for i, folder_location in zip(url, folder):
    time.sleep(1)
    response = requests.get(i)
    soup= BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
    for link in soup.select("[href$='.pdf']"):

        filename = os.path.join(folder_location,link['href'].split('/')[-1])
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(requests.get(urljoin(i,link['href'])).content)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. It will put the files in the PDF folder.

```
import os
from simplified_scrapy import Spider, SimplifiedDoc, SimplifiedMain, utils

class MySpider(Spider):
    name = 'download_pdf'
    allowed_domains = ["www.adb.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "https://www.adb.org/projects/documents/country/ban/year/2020?terms=education",
        "https://www.adb.org/projects/documents/country/ban/year/2019?terms=education",
        "https://www.adb.org/projects/documents/country/ban/year/2018?terms=education"
    ]  # Entry page

    def __init__(self):
        Spider.__init__(self, self.name)  #necessary
        if (not os.path.exists('./pdfs')):
            os.mkdir('./pdfs')

    def afterResponse(self, response, url, error=None, extra=None):
        try:
            path = './pdfs' + url[url.rindex('/'):]
            index = path.find('?')
            if index > 0: path = path[:index]
            flag = utils.saveResponseAsFile(response, path, fileType="pdf")
            if flag:
                return None
            else:  # If it's not a pdf, leave it to the frame
                return Spider.afterResponse(self, response, url, error)
        except Exception as err:
            print(err)

    def extract(self, url, html, models, modelNames):
        doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
        lst = doc.selects('div.list >a').contains("documents/", attr="href")
        if not lst:
            lst = doc.selects('div.hidden-md hidden-lg >a')
        urls = []
        for a in lst:
            a["url"] = utils.absoluteUrl(url.url, a["href"])
            urls.append(a)

        return {"Urls": urls}


SimplifiedMain.startThread(MySpider())  # Start download
```

The pdf from each url be downloaded to each separate folder.

```
from simplified_scrapy import Spider, SimplifiedDoc, SimplifiedMain, utils

class MySpider(Spider):
    name = 'download_pdf'
    allowed_domains = ["www.adb.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "https://www.adb.org/projects/documents/country/ban/year/2020?terms=education",
        "https://www.adb.org/projects/documents/country/ban/year/2019?terms=education",
        "https://www.adb.org/projects/documents/country/ban/year/2018?terms=education"
    ]  # Entry page

    def afterResponse(self, response, url, error=None, extra=None):
        if not extra:
            print ("The version of library simplified_scrapy is too old, please update.")
            SimplifiedMain.setRunFlag(False)
            return
        try:
            path = './pdfs'
            # create folder start
            srcUrl = extra.get('srcUrl')
            if srcUrl:
                index = srcUrl.find('year/')
                year = ''
                if index > 0:
                    year = srcUrl[index + 5:]
                    index = year.find('?')
                    if index>0:
                        path = path + year[:index]
                        utils.createDir(path)
            # create folder end

            path = path + url[url.rindex('/'):]
            index = path.find('?')
            if index > 0: path = path[:index]
            flag = utils.saveResponseAsFile(response, path, fileType="pdf")
            if flag:
                return None
            else:  # If it's not a pdf, leave it to the frame
                return Spider.afterResponse(self, response, url, error, extra)
        except Exception as err:
            print(err)

    def extract(self, url, html, models, modelNames):
        doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
        lst = doc.selects('div.list >a').contains("documents/", attr="href")
        if not lst:
            lst = doc.selects('div.hidden-md hidden-lg >a')
        urls = []
        for a in lst:
            a["url"] = utils.absoluteUrl(url.url, a["href"])
            # Set root url start
            a["srcUrl"] = url.get('srcUrl')
            if not a['srcUrl']:
                a["srcUrl"] = url.url
            # Set root url end
            urls.append(a)

        return {"Urls": urls}

    # Download again by resetting the URL. Called when you want to download again.
    def resetUrl(self):
        Spider.clearUrl(self)
        Spider.resetUrlsTest(self)

SimplifiedMain.startThread(MySpider())  # Start download
```

Comment: Thank you for this very helpful answer. Sorry for my ignorance, but which folder are pdfs being downloaded to? I have replaced ./pdf with my desktop path but it seems like not being downloaded to the folder. 
Also, may I ask how the pdf from each URL can be downloaded to each separate folder?

Comment: @crackers This line in the code is used to set the file storage path: path = '/ pdfs' + url[ url.rindex ('/'):]. It can be stored in different folders, but it's a little more complicated. I'll try to change it.

Comment: Thank you. That would be really helpful. I am trying to write a loop but it seems very complicated for a novice like me. Thanks again.

Comment: another problem I am facing is that the code runs on the same URL only once. If I want to run it again on the same URL it does not work.

Comment: @crackers Yes, it has the function of removing duplicate data. If you want to run again during the test, you need to delete the file under the folder /db before running.

Comment: Thank you so much for the update. I have tried by removing the files from the folder but it would not still crawl on the same URL twice.

Comment: In addition, I get the error message of `simplified-scrapy stopped` when I run the updated code to download files in each folder. Sorry for bringing this hassle again.

Comment: @crackers Did you also see this sentence: "The version of library simplified_scrapy is too old, please update.". If so, execute the update command: pip install -U simplified_scrapy.

Comment: @crackers Leave me a message if you have any problems. It doesn't matter:)

Comment: @dabinsou Many thanks. It works now after updating. However, the code cannot still crawl on the same URL twice even after deleting files from the folder. Is there a way to overcome this issue?

Comment: @crackers Yes, you can download it again after deletion, not twice. It can also be set by code. But I don't understand why you download it twice. I updated the code, you try it.

Comment: @dabinsou Thank you for this. At first, I was testing on some URLs so have not saved the files. That's why I need to redownload the files. But seems like even after clearing URLs, the code does not crawl and download any files.

Comment: @crackers Is it because you're looking for the wrong place? If you do not change the code, after running, three new files will be created in the current directory: pdfs2020, pdfs2019 and pdfs2018. In addition, after running the code, do you have any errors there?

Comment: sorry my late reply. The new code runs on new URLs and creates pdfs2020, pdfs2019 and pdfs2018. But when I re-run on the same URLs, it does not run. It just continues with `('simplified-scrapy is running......',)` indefinitely but does not download any file again. I have also tried by deleting the folders it created and get the same results.

Comment: @crackers Delete the DB folder and try running it agai.

Comment: you mean these folders (pdfs2020, pdfs2019 and pdfs2018)? I have deleted them. Still not working.

Comment: @crackers No, it's folder /db in the root directory.

Comment: You're welcome. If you have any questions in the future, just leave me a message.

Comment: Thank you. That's very kind of you. I will not hesitate to reach out. Best.

Comment: Hi @dabingsou Thanks for your offer earlier to reach out if I have similar questions. Would be kind enough to have a look at this problem I have posted in the following URL when you have a moment please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66609022/downloading-files-by-crawling-sub-urls-in-python

Comment: @crackers Sorry, I saw it late. But congratulations on finding the answer.